# How to downgrade Bugzilla from version 4.4.4 to 4.4.2 or 4.4.3?

Tags: maven-plugin, bugzilla, downgrade

I updated bugzilla from 4.4.2 to 4.4.4 and now the bugzilla-maven-plugin isn't working (reason [here](http://bzr.mozilla.org/bugzilla/4.4/revision/8663) and [here](http://bzr.mozilla.org/bugzilla/4.4/revision/8664)  ).So  I need to downgrade to the 4.4.2 downgrade is not supported

This is the command I used for the upgrade:

```
sudo bzr up -r tag:bugzilla-4.4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

When changes are minor, and no database changes are involved, and this is the case between 4.4.2 and 4.4.4, it's posible to downgrade using the next command:

```
sudo bzr revert -r tag:bugzilla-4.4.2
```

Remember to do a `./checksetup.pl` after the downgrade.

It is possible that doing `bzr up` instead also works as expected, but I don't tested it.